# Select certain files from a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

We maintain a folder filled with excel reports that are organized by date. I'm trying to find a way that we can view the data of a few columns in each workbook but only for a given date range . What I'm really struggling with is finding a way to only open the information

```
WORKDIR = "Z:\BackOrder Reports"
DESKTOP = 'c:' + os.environ['HOMEPATH'] + "\Desktop"
os.chdir(DESKTOP)


Firstdate = raw_input("Set first date range Note: Format YYYY-MM-DD:")
if len(Firstdate) > 0:
    True
else:
    print 'test break 1'

Seconddate = raw_input("Set second date range Note: Format YYYY-MM-DD:")
if len(Seconddate) > 0:
    True
else:
    print 'test break 2'

name = "Number of backorders %s through %s" % (Firstdate, Seconddate)
```

I'm sure there is a better way to write this whole thing but don't really know of one yet. I'm still in the early stages of learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `openpyxl` module.

There's a really good write-up on how to use it to read Excel spreadsheets here: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

This includes reading and parsing dates.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Its been difficult finding useful modules like this that are dumbed down enough for my to fully comprehend.

Comment: No problem at all. I'm glad I could help. If you found the answer useful, then please don't forget to _accept_ it.  And good luck with your program.